# How to connect to a computer without public IP?

Tags: android, delphi, networking

I have a simple app idea in my mind and I need to know how to connect from an Android application (client) to a Windows application (Delphi, server).

There is no need to be specific about the platform, I am familiar with networks in Delphi using winsock or Indy and I'm sure I will be able to figure out the appropriate mechanism in Android.

**What I need to know** is how to connect to a server (computer), which doesn't have its own public IP *and* is not in the same network as the client (one can be behind a local router, while the other might be connecting to the internet through 3G, for instance). This should be possible, as many programs work like that (remote desktop programs, TeamViewer, for instance: one computer is assigned an ID and using this ID other computer can connect to it.) I will not have access to the routers behind which the app will be running, so port forwarding is not an option.

I have a working network app, but that only works in LAN, so I'm guessing somewhat another approach is needed.

Thanks for answers

Comment: It's not magic. There needs to be a route from point A to point B. "Many program work like that" because there is a path from one computer to the other. Without that path, there is no communication. You will need to set up a "computer" that is a link between you and the computer you want to talk to and that is able to talk to both endpoints.

Comment: You should read about [tunneling connection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the programs that work that way still use a server with a public IP.  Each side of the client connections to the server to say "here I am".  The public server can then shuffle data between the two clients.

That still leaves a lot of questions regarding the communication between the public server and each client - i.e. pull vs. push for taking data that was sent to the server and getting it back down to the second client.

You may want to read the [specification for Copilot](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/AardvarkSpec.html) (originally named Project Aardvark).  Joel Spolsky published the specification when the started the project.  It talks about their use of a reflector service.

> **The Reflector**
>   A Windows Service which we run on our servers, used to
>   allow any helper to help any victim even when  both of them are behind
>   firewalls. Both helper and victim connect to the reflector. The
>   reflector checks  that they are authorized and relays messages between
>   helper and victim until the paid-up time runs out

Answer (score 4):

you could put an intermediate server which they can both route for "nat traversal".

otherwise you will have to put port forwarding on one of those computer's local router to allow incoming connections to be forwarded to the computer.

Comment: with at least one server with a public IP you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching to let both parties connect directly

Comment: This hole punching method sounds pretty neat.. I thought I'd have to use a middle-man server, but I have yet to figure out exactly how. Now that I know how the approach is called, the searching will be a lot easier. Thanks

Comment: there can be ready-made intermediate services. Out of memory - hamachi.cc and TeamViewer. Though that would tie you to their clients on both ends. Maybe You'd stick for some P2P libraries, liek Skype and Torrents. There were research general-purpose p2p libraries, not custom-tilored to file- or voice-exchange.